# Catch ORA exceptions in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle

I wrote a package to add records in a country table that has a reference key pointing to a "regions" table using region_id.So,if I try to add a "region_id" in my countries table and if that value does not exist in my regions table,I should throw the exception and catch.
My package code is:

```
CREATE PACKAGE BODY cus7 AS
v_error_code NUMBER;
region_exists pls_integer;

 procedure addi6 (c_cntry_id in out countries.country_id%type,
                                       c_cntr_name in countries.country_name%type, 
                                       c_rgn_id in countries.region_id%type)
is

begin
    begin
        select 1 into region_exists
        from regions r 
        where r.region_id = c_rgn_id;
    exception
        when no_data_found then

region_exists := 0;            
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Region not present');




    end;




    if region_exists = 1 then
         insert into countries(country_id, country_name,region_id)
         values (c_cntry_id, c_cntr_name, c_rgn_id);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserted');
END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN dup_val_on_index
  THEN 
    c_cntry_id := null;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Already present');

end addi6;

END cus7;
/
```

Now,in my procedure,everything is working fine,except when I do an add like this:

```
DECLARE
   outputValue CHAR(2) := 'KO';
begin
  cus7.addi6(outputValue,'KOREA',5);

end;
/
```

apart from getting my own message which is "Region not found",I am also getting ORA-01403-No data found.

My question is if there is a way to catch this ORA exception or avoid display?

Tx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all you have to do is add `WHEN OTHERS` to your exception block in order to catch all of the other possible `ORA` exceptions.

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN dup_val_on_index
        THEN 
            c_cntry_id := null;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Already present')
  WHEN OTHERS
        THEN 
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Another Error');
            -- other logic here
```

Here is an [extensive documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm) regarding error handling in PL/SQL.